# Trying to display values from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables in SQL, one of which contains the employee ID (emp_id) and their first, and last name. Another table contains the employee ID with their total sales. I want to see the first name, last name, and their total sales of only those records where the total sales are higher than 25,000. The first table's name is employee, and the second table's name is works_with

The code that I used is:

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name,works_with.total_sales
FROM employee
WHERE employee.emp_id IN (
    SELECT works_with.emp_id
    FROM works_with
    WHERE works_with.total_sales>25000
);
```

I'm getting the following error:

"Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
The multi-part identifier "works_with.total_sales" could not be bound."

How can I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but you need to use the JOIN statement, this statement is used when you want to join the result of two tables together. this link helps you : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

The join statement would be as @etch_45 suggested.

Comment: w3f**ls... I wouldn't recommend that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query still works if writing like this:

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name
FROM employee
WHERE employee.emp_id IN (
    SELECT works_with.emp_id
    FROM works_with
    WHERE works_with.total_sales>25000
);
```

Your select is failed because it doesn't have the column `works_with.total_sales`.
You can add `works_with.total_sales` to your select with the `join` clause like this:

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name, works_with.total_sales
FROM employee
JOIN works_with
    on employee.emp_id=works_with.emp_id
    WHERE works_with.total_sales>25000
```

Or select multiple tables like this:

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name, works_with.total_sales
FROM employee, works_with
WHERE employee.emp_id=works_with.emp_id
    and works_with.total_sales>25000
```

**Explain the error**
`The multi-part identifier "works_with.total_sales" could not be bound`

- That tells you the `works_with.total_sales` isn't available in the current selection.
- You can't bound it to your selection.

see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for `join` clause in `t-SQL`

Answer (score 0):

This query might work given your requirements. A `JOIN` could be used to link those two tables in your question.

```
select t1.first_name,
    t1.last_name,
    t2.total_sales
    from employees t1
    join works_with t2
    on t2.emp_id = t1.emp_id
    where t2.total_sales > 25000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join bth tables and show all rows with where the total_sales is bigger than 2500

```
SELECT employee.first_name, employee.last_name,works_with.total_sales
FROM employee INNER JOIN works_with ON works_with.emp_id = employee.emp_id 
WHERE  works_with.total_sales>25000;
```